# How to apply formula to cells with value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm using vba and have managed to apply the below code, to add 'A' to cells in each column (X, AK, AW) value.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("X2:X24").Select
For Each X In Selection
If X.Value <> "" Then X.Value = X.Value & "A"
Next
ActiveSheet.Range("AK2:AK24").Select
For Each AK In Selection
If AK.Value <> "" Then AK.Value = AK.Value & "A"
Next
ActiveSheet.Range("AW2:AW24").Select
For Each AW In Selection
If AW.Value <> "" Then AW.Value = AW.Value & "A"
```

However, I am now trying to apply the below formulas to columns Y, Z, AA & AB. I only want this to apply from the 2nd cell downwards and only for cells that have value. So from Y2 down unless the cell is empty. I can't seem to get it to work!

```
=TODAY()-1     

=TEXT(TODAY(),"YYYYMM")

=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMM YYYY")
```

Comment: What exactly did you try with these three entries, and how did that not work?

Comment: Range("AB2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(TODAY(),""MMM YYYY"")" Is where I started, which fills the first cell. But I don't know where to go from there. I am completely new to this so have tried a few things but I am chancing it rather than using any kind of knowledge!

Comment: figured I could insert the code - If AB.Value <> "" Then AB.Value = "=TEXT(TODAY(),""MMM YYYY"")" but this failed with "object required"
And I have changed the range to "AB2:AB100" as objects will never fall out of this range. I just need AB1 to not change

Comment: You want to apply 3 formulas to 4 columns? (if so, which formula(s) to which column?)

Comment: J & Z:
=TODAY()-1     
AA:
=TEXT(TODAY(),"YYYYMM")
AB:
=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMM YYYY")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will dynamically determine the last used row with data in col Y

Copies the range A2:BA+lastRow to an array, loops every row, and assigns each formula per column (if the cell is not empty). Then places the array back on the range

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SetFormulasToNonEmptyCells()

  Dim ur As Range, arr As Variant, r As Long

  'The selected columns start at A (col 1) to BA (col 53)
  Set ur = Sheet1.Range("A2:BA" & Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row)

  arr = ur
  For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 10))) > 0 Then arr(r, 10) = "=TODAY()-1"                  'J  (10)
    If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 22))) > 0 Then arr(r, 22) = "-1"                          'V  (22)
    If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 25))) > 0 Then arr(r, 25) = "1"                           'Y  (25)
    If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 26))) > 0 Then arr(r, 26) = "1"                           'X  (26)
    If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 27))) > 0 Then arr(r, 27) = "=TEXT(TODAY(),""YYYYMM"")"   'AA (27)
    If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 28))) > 0 Then arr(r, 28) = "=TEXT(TODAY(),""MMM YYYY"")" 'AB (28)
    If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 46))) > 0 Then arr(r, 46) = "-1"                          'AT (46)
  Next
  ur.Formula = arr
  ur.Columns(4).NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy" 'Use col #'s instead of letters
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Amazing that worked perfectly, thanks a lot! I made a slight change and added a 5th row. The only issue now is that the formula for 4 is producing 'Apr-18', instead of 'Apr 2018' as it was before, how do I change this?
Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped. I added version2 - formats the cells after inserting the values

Comment: Brilliant that solved it! One more question if you don't mind! I tried to paste another formula to times cells in V & AT, with value, by -1 but the following failed.. (it worked previously but fails when pasted into your formula)
     
If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 2))) > 0 Then arr(r, 2) = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "-1" 'col v

No errors are shown but it does stop the other lines from working completely (I don't have enough characters to post the entire thing). 

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks, ended w/this but not working..

If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 1))) > 0 Then arr(r, 1) = "=TODAY()-1"     'Col j
If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 2))) > 0 Then arr(r, 2) = "-1"                      'Col v
If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 3))) > 0 Then arr(r, 3) = "=TODAY() "1"    'Col y
If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 4))) > 0 Then arr(r, 4) = "=TODAY() "1"    'Col z
If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 5))) > 0 Then arr(r, 5) = "=TEXT(TODAY(),""YYYYMM"")"    'Col AA
If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 6))) > 0 Then arr(r, 6) = "=TEXT(TODAY(),""MMM YYYY"")"                'Col AB
If Len(Trim$(arr(r, 7))) > 0 Then arr(r, 7) = "-1"                      'col AT

Comment: Cheers for all of the help, Paul you're a gent!

Comment: A - BA.  
The first column that needs editing is J and last is AW. 
I also need to add a change in O but it is only adding plain text so I'll be able to work that one out. (Replace text with "Credit Note for Invoice"). 
Thanks

Comment: Ok I made the update - you will be able to update any column, **but**: you have to use column numbers (not letters), and you need to update the column number in 2 places on the same row. Also, in your formulas don't use multiple equal signs, and don't have any extra spaces; example `"=TODAY() "1"` is not a valid formula. Test your formulas in a Cell first. If a formula contains quotations, you must use double quotations in the string, so if the formula in an Excel cell is `="A" & "B"`, to use this formula in VBA you must use it like this `"=""A"" & ""B"""`. Hope this helps!